# Woocommerce cart only work for Logged in user

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I use this code to add item on cart and it's work fine only for logged in user, When I check in incognito window then cart show empty I also remove cache but this is not the cache issue

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
add_action('init', 'handle_custom_action', 999, 1);

function handle_custom_action() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
        $product_id_reinstatement = 12172; 
        $product_id_course_extension = 12173;
        $variation_id = null;
        $variation = array();       

        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
            // Set a temporary user for cart operations
            wp_set_current_user(0);
            
            // Initialize the WC_Session_Handler object
            if (!isset(WC()->session)) {
                WC()->session = new WC_Session_Handler();
                WC()->session->init();
            }
        }
        // Check if guest checkout is enabled
        $guest_checkout_enabled = get_option('woocommerce_enable_guest_checkout');
        if (isset($woocommerce->cart)) {
            if (isset($_POST['re_instatement'])) {
                $re_instatement = $_POST['re_instatement'];
                $product_name = '( ' . implode(', ', $re_instatement) . ' )';
                $tprice_reinstatement = 0;
                if (is_array($re_instatement)) {
                    foreach ($re_instatement as $value) {
                        $tprice_reinstatement += 150;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "No values selected for Dropdown 1.<br>";
                }
                $cart_item_data = array('custom_price' => $tprice_reinstatement, 'Course Code'=>$product_name);   
                
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id_reinstatement, 1, $variation_id, $variation,  $cart_item_data );
                
                $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
                
                $woocommerce->cart->set_session();
                
                $woocommerce->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();
            }
            if (isset($_POST['course_extension'])) {
                $course_extension = $_POST['course_extension'];
                $product_name = '( ' . implode(', ', $course_extension) . ' )';
                $tprice_course_extension = 0;
                if (is_array($course_extension)) {
                    foreach ($course_extension as $value) {
                        $tprice_course_extension += 125;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "No values selected for Dropdown 2.<br>";
                }

                $cart_item_data = array('custom_price' => $tprice_course_extension, 'Course Code'=> $product_name);   
                
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id_course_extension, 1, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
                
                $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
                
                $woocommerce->cart->set_session();
                
                $woocommerce->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();

            }
            wp_redirect(wc_get_cart_url());
            exit();
                
        }
    }
    
}
```

I want the id which I mentioned in the code also add to the cart for non logged in user.

Comment: This is because I am using the init hook. I should use for this template_redirect hook.